# Save instance loaded from one session on a different session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, windows-services

Perhaps my search skills are poor today but anyway, Is it wrong or may have side effects, to get an instance using one session object, and then go and save that instance on a different session object?

I ask cause once I refactored my code to do this, I am getting many problems, like it creating new records on the database even though the instance was already persisted.

Thanks

Comment: just curious, but wouldn't it make more sense to maybe do this work in the Application context?  

It seems liek you answered your own quesiton though: you're getting weird sideeffects.

Comment: this is a windows service and multi threading is involved.

Comment: Thanks. I mis-read that I saw 'session' and thought asp.net.

You *can* move objects between sessions by attaching and reattaching them. I've looked at it before but ended up going a different route.

This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272719/how-to-maintain-an-object-for-two-nhibernate-sessions

Answer (score 2):

Use `Merge` method:

```
newSession.Merge(entity);
newSession.Save(entity);
```